# Anchor to different page to specific id not working on mobile (wordpress)

Tags: html, mobile, navbar, anchor

I have 3 menus with subitems in my navbar, those subitems are linked to specific sections `id` of the main page as such:

```
<ul id="navbar">
 <li id="idli1" class="listli">
  <a href="https://www.site.co/page/">navbar-Item1</a>
 </li>

 <li id="idli2" class="listli">
  <a href="https://www.site.co/page/">navbar-Item2</a>
  <ul class="sublist">

   <li id="idsubli1" class="sublistli"> 
   <a href="https://www.site.co/page/#id1" class="classname">sub-Item 1</a></li>

   <li id="idsubli2" class="sublistli"> 
   <a href="https://www.site.co/page/#id2" class="classname">sub-Item 2</a></li>

   <li id="idsubli3" class="sublistli"> 
   <a href="https://www.site.co/page/#id3" class="classname">sub-Item 3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>

 <li id="idli3" class="listli">
  <a href="https://www.site.co/page/">navbar-Item3</a>
 </li>

</ul>
```

On desktop everything works fine.

On mobile the link seems to not be valid, the formula `https://www.site.co/page/#id` doesn't work.
Clicking on the submenu just close the submenu.

If i remove the section `id` from the link, the subitem works and goes to the page.

you can check the menu [here](https://www.enjoyfisiotraining.com/)

am i missing something about mobile and anchors?
i really don't understand what is the problem about those links.

Answer (score 0):

on mobile your navbar collapse from what I have seen so maybe its being assigned an id that you have used in your menu already thus the link won't work - ids should be unique